# WebSocket JSON javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery, json, websocket

I'm sending JSON via a websocket, but some of the created messages are empty.

```
function chVol(vol){
 var send = {};
 send["payload"] = {};
 send["payload"]["volume"] = vol;
 ws.send(JSON.stringify(send));
}
```

If vol has the value 0 or 1, the messages are correct and at some other values of vol, too. I'm changing vol with a slider and when I'm logging JSON.stringify(send) all messages are correct, but not when

```
ws.onmessage = function (e) {
            data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            console.log(data);
};
```

is called. Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. `onmessage` is for incoming messages, it won't log outgoing messages you sent using `.send()`. Is that the confusion?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this:

```
var send = {};
send["payload"]["volume"] = vol;
```

That will cause an exception, as you're attempting to access the property `'volume'` on `undefined`.

You need to first initialize `send['payload']` to an empty object:

```
var send = {}
send['payload'] = {}
send['payload']['volume'] = vol
```

Comment: Or you could make the definition in to a single object declaration: `var send = { payload: { volume: vol } };` +1 for fixing the problem regardless.

Comment: i didn't copy the whole code, because there a much more parameters that I submit. 
send["payload"] = {}; is in the code before...

Comment: @JohannesGi then please update your question and include code that actually works. It's important to include a minimal **complete** example, otherwise we cannot help you.